# jQuery how to remove id tag from anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello I am new with jQuery and learning so I need your help to fix my issue.

I am using jQuery ajax and I want to remove id attribute from anchor link after ajax success.

For example I have this link:

```
<a id="like_14" href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>
```

And want this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>
```

Note: I don't want to use `id="like_14"` after ajax success. completely removed from anchor link.

My Ajax Code Is:

```
$(function () {
        $('.load_more_ctnt .ovrly a').live("click", function () {
            var getImageID = $(this).attr("id");
            if (getImageID) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo URL; ?>home/passImageID",
                    data: "getImageID=" + getImageID,
                    success: function (html) {
                        alert(getImageID);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                 //$(".more_tab").html('The End');
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

I am getting ID from this variable: `var getImageID = $(this).attr("id");`

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Use .removeAttr(attributeName)....

Comment: why do you want to remove a default attribute? doesn't look good to me..

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tf46C/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `.removeAttr()`

```
$("#like_14").removeAttr("id");
```

Then your code will look like

```
$(function () {
    $('.load_more_ctnt .ovrly a').live("click", function () {
        var getImageID = $(this).attr("id");
        if (getImageID) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo URL; ?>home/passImageID",
                data: "getImageID=" + getImageID,
                success: function (html) {
                    alert(getImageID);
                    $("#" + getImageID).removeAttr("id");
                }
            });
        } else {
            //$(".more_tab").html('The End');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: smarter: `$("#" + getImageID).removeAttr("id");`

Answer (score 2):

Use `.removeAttr()` in jquery.

```
$(this).removeAttr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace id with blank:

```
$("#like_14").attr("id","");
```

or remove

```
$("#like_14").removeAttr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (html) {
                        //alert(getImageID);

                       $('#'+getImageID).removeAttr('id');
                    }
```

[Rerence](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)